# How to open UIViewcontroller from a UISplitViewController (left side tableview)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, uisplitview

I have one `UISplitView` Controller and on left side i can see `UISplitView` tableview part and right hand side i can `UIViewController` view.

I added one `UIBarButton` to `UITableViewController` (`navigationbar`)  and when i clicked on `UIBarButton` (on left side `UITableView`) it showing following error message in console.

```
"
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "3rQ-6t-ad4-view-1Zq-6N-cLc" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'

"
```

How to load a new `UIViewController` from `UISplitView` in iOS ?
Pls help me

Answer (score 0):

Can you make your question more clear?
As far as I can understand your UITableViewController's view was nil when it tried to access it. Hence it called loadView function to make the view. Can you check whether you have connected all the outlets correctly . This is the commonest mistakes that the newbies in iOS make.Comment when you have checked that.